# How to delete blank rows in between the sheet using POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to delete blank row from Excel sheet using POI.

We have method like `shiftRow()` or `removeRow()` but its not for use
in this case. Please help me to get it done.

Comment: May be an helpful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf

Answer (score 4):

Please try following piece of code. It works for me as well when more than one consecutive blank rows existing.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
        if(sheet.getRow(i)==null){
            isRowEmpty=true;
            sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
            i--;
        continue;
        }
        for(int j =0; j<sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();j++){
            if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString().trim().equals("")){
                isRowEmpty=true;
            }else {
                isRowEmpty=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isRowEmpty==true){
            sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Changes to @Sankumarsingh code to make it work

@Sankumarsingh code did not work for me as it was not removing empty first row. Fix for this issue is:

```
private void removeEmptyRows(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    Boolean isRowEmpty = Boolean.FALSE;
    for(int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
      if(sheet.getRow(i)==null){
        isRowEmpty=true;
        sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, -1);
        i--;
        continue;
      }
      for(int j =0; j<sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();j++){
        if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j) == null || 
        sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString().trim().equals("")){
          isRowEmpty=true;
        }else {
          isRowEmpty=false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(isRowEmpty==true){
        sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, -1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not tested, try this:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
sheet.removeRow(row);
```

Comment: this will only remove content of row.i want to delete the the blank row between the two data filled row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to break the reading of cells when they have deleted rows taken as non-blank rows

```
while(cellsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell currentCell = cellsIterator.next();

                if(currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    this.currentArraySheet.put("Headers",this.currentArraySheetHeaders);
                    this.currentArraySheet.put("Rows",this.currentArraySheetRows);
                    return;
                }

                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + " | ");
                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "| ");
                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.println(currentCell.getBooleanCellValue() + " | ");
                }
}
```