# delete Excel row containing specific text using Apache_poi

Tags: java, excel, swing, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to remove an Excel row which has specific data.Ex:delete a row where student roll number is 1.Below is what i have done so far but it won't work.

```
   String personal=personal1.getSelectedItem().toString();
   String roll=classper.getText();
   String ps="personal";
   InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("D:\\" + personal + ps + ".xls");
   Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
   Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
   Row Row = null;
   Cell Cell = null;
   int LastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
   for(int RowNum= 0;RowNum<LastRowNum-1;RowNum++){
        Row=sheet.getRow(RowNum);
        for(int CellNum = 0; CellNum<Row.getLastCellNum();CellNum++){
           Cell = Row.getCell(CellNum);
           String TextInCell=Cell.toString();
           if(TextInCell.contains(roll)){
              sheet.shiftRows(RowNum+1, LastRowNum, -1);
              LastRowNum--;
              RowNum--;
              break;
           }
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that you need to save the workbook after you apply changes. Add these:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("file name");
book.write(out);
```

Also note that if the desired row is the last one, you should call `sheet.removeRow(rowIndex);` instead of `shiftRows`.

Another observation, you are skipping the last row in the `for` loop as you are running until `LastRowNum-1`. It should be:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3554129/1048330) is an example of `removeRow()` implementation.