# Unable to understand working of shiftRows method of apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working with .xls file i am going to translate(shift) Rows of excell table to specific position.But got unwanted results everytime.I had already gone through documentation of method shiftRows.Unable to understand working of this statement.

```
sheet.shiftRows(34, sheet.getLastRowNum(), processIndex-4);
```

Sometimes it shifted two rows in Excell Table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf also uses shiftRows and it does not seem to work as one would assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        sheet.shiftRows(int startRow, int endRow, int n);
```

is used to Shift number of rows down the sheet .
where

- startRow =At which we need to insert row .
- endRows  = Total rows
- n = How much rows we are going to insert

The javadoc for [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.shiftRows](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftRows-int-int-int-) provides more details.

Comment: Would be great if you could link to the [javadocs for the method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftRows%28int,%20int,%20int%29) in your answer!

Comment: Parameter description is as below
`startRow - the row to start shifting`
`endRow - the row to end shifting`
`n - the number of rows to shift`