# Remove and shift rows in excel using java code

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel where rows have values 1 or  0 in column F. In my new excel I should have the rows only with value 0.
I want to remove all the rows having value '1' in  their column F and no blank rows should be displayed in its place.Only rows with value 0 
in column F should appear in new excel.

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream("Input.xls");

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            HSSFWorkbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook();
            wb2 = wb;

            Row row;
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            int getLastCell=row.getLastCellNum()-1;
            int lastIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

            for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
                row=sheet.getRow(i);
                Cell cell=row.getCell(getLastCell);
                if(cell!=null && (formatter.formatCellValue(cell).equals(filterValue)))
                          {
                            sheet.removeRow(row);
                           int rowIndexToDelete = row.getRowNum();
                          sheet.shiftRows(rowIndexToDelete+1, lastIndex, -1);

                        }           

            }       
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Output.xls");
            wb2.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
```

Comment: So, does your code work?  What goes wrong?  What's the issue?  What's your question?

Comment: My code works but I get empty rows in my output excel.In my output excel I want only rows having value 0 in column F should be displayed no empty rows should appear..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf